# Solve the Cauchy problem by the method of characteristic $pz+q=1$ with initial data $y=x,z=x/2$ . Indicate the region where the solution is valid.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

Solve the Cauchy problem by the method of characteristic $pz+q=1$ with initial data $y=x, z=x/2$. Indicate the region where the solution is valid.

How to solve this problem.

Lagrange's auxiliary equation $$\frac{dx}{z}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{dz}{1}$$
Integrating $y-z=c_1$, $z^2-2x=c_2$.

Using $y=x, z=x/2$ i.e. $y=x=t, z=t/2$, the equations  $y-z=c_1$, $z^2-2x=c_2$ give $t=2c_1$, $t^2-8t=4c_2$.

Eliminating $t$, we have $c_1^2-4c_1-c_2=0$.

**If it is right, what will be the solution? Please indicate the region where the solution is valid.**
By putting $c_1$, $C_2$, is $(y-z)^2-4(y-z)-(z^2-2x)=0$ the solution?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dx}{z}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{dz}{1}\quad\text{is OK.}$$
OK for the characteristic equations $\quad y-z=c_1\quad$ and $\quad z^2-2x=c_2$.

The general solution $\Phi(c_1\:,\:c_2)=0$ is :
$$\Phi(y-z\:,\:z^2-2x)=0$$
$Phi$ is an arbitrary function on two variables.

Or on the form of implicit equation :
$$\boxed{z^2-2x=F(y-z)}$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to the specified condition).

Condition : $y=x, z=\frac12 x \quad\implies\quad (\frac12 x)^2-2x=F(x-\frac12 x)$

Let $X=\frac12 x$

$(\frac12 x)^2-2x=F(x-\frac12 x)=(X)^2-4X=F(X)$
$$F(X)=X^2-4X$$
The function $F(X)$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where $X=y-z$.
$$z^2-2x=(y-z)^2-4(y-z)$$
This is consistent with the solution that you found. Your solution is valid.

After simplification :
$$z(x,y)=\frac{y^2-4y+2x}{2(y-2)}$$

Comment: indicate the region where the solution is valid

Comment: Is the solution valid for $y\neq 2$. What will be the answer. Region =$\{(x,y): x,y\in \mathbb{R}, y\neq 2\}$

Comment: OK.............